# similar to landau's function, but all elements are odd

Tags: number-theory, optimization, gcd-and-lcm, integer-partitions

Everyone knows about landau's function, then I was curious about the lcm of partition "n" which element's are all odd numbers.

for example:

$$8=3+5 \Rightarrow f(8)=15$$

$$19=3+5+11 \Rightarrow f(19)=165$$

do you have any idea related or know some OEIS related to this?

Comment: Please avoid saying "Everyone knows ..." because that's guaranteed wrong. Please complete questions, this also increases the response rate. You can use links.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3440621/permutation-with-largest-odd-order) is probably the same question, but since it's not clear what exactly you're asking for I'm not entirely sure.